# How to convert only time (type as string) into UTC time format without using the entire date?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, utc

I have a dropdown options with local times in starting 12am-11:30pm:

```
<select> 
<option value="12:00am">12:00am</option>
<option value="12:30am"/>12:30am</option>
<option value="1:00am"/>1:00am</option>
<option value="1:30am"/>1:30am</option>
<option value="2:00am"/>2:00am</option>
.....
.....
.....
<option value="11:30pm">11:30pm</option>
</select>

<select> 
    <option value=this.getUTCVal("12:00am")>this.getUTCVal("12:00am")</option>
    .....
    .....
    .....
    <option value=this.getUTCVal("11:30pm")>this.getUTCVal("11:30pm")</option>
    </select>
```

these values are in the array:

```
var arr=["12:00am","12:30am"....."11:30pm"];
```

The datepicker that allows to select the date:

the `DatePicker` is a react-datepicker- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

```
<DatePicker
                        startDate={startDateVal}
                        endDate={endDateVal} />
```

I'd like to display an equivalent UTC time for all the values. So I checked resources and most of them uses the standard format of conversion with date.

```
date = new Date(); 
var now_utc =  Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),
 date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());

 return new Date(now_utc);
```

However I dont have a full date and I only can pass times values as arguments to a function.
I tried:

```
getUTCVal(val) {
  Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) // which give me current time
}
```

I also tried:

```
var datestring = "1:00";
new Date(datestring); //gives me invalid date
```

Now I'm not sure how can I convert the time without having the actual date..

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you assuming the time string is on the current day in local time?

Comment: thats the problem, @JimB., could be any date. current date, past date

Comment: Technically, you don't know what the offset UTC is unless you know the date.  Summer/Winter/Standard/Daylight time.

Comment: When you say that the dropdown options represent "local times", do you mean that they represent local time "today" or is there some other date context for these times?

Comment: so here is the issue: this is specifically for picking time values, there is another dropdown that picks date, and this date could be nay date, current date, past date, may be future date as well..so depending on the selected date value, the time would reflect

Comment: the datepicker is from  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the user selected date as context before converting the user selected time from local to UTC. Then, it is just a matter of creating a `Date` object using the user selected date and time so that you can retrieve the UTC time parts with `getUTCHours` and `getUTCMinutes`.

Below is an example with an arbitrary input date and time (you just need to get the `inputDate` and `inputHour` values on user selection from your inputs). Also, note that you may need to adjust how the input date is handled based on the data format that is produced by your date picker control.

```js
const getUTCTime = (d) => `${d.getUTCHours()}:${d.getUTCMinutes()} UTC`;
const inputDate = '2018-10-22';
const inputTime = '1:30PM';
const [y, m, d] = inputDate.split('-');
const date = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
let [hh, mm] = inputTime.match(/\d+/g).map((x) => parseInt(x));
let [ap] = inputTime.match(/[a-z]+/i);
ap = ap.toLowerCase()
if (ap === 'pm') {
  hh = hh < 12 ? hh + 12 : 0;
}

date.setHours(hh, mm);
console.log(getUTCTime(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  Compute the offset to local time, then adjust hours accordingly:

```
const dateString="1:00pm";
const now = new Date();
const offset = now.getUTCHours() - now.getHours();

let hours = parseInt(dateString.split(':')[0]);
const minutes = parseInt(dateString.replace(/^.*:([0-9]*)[a-z]*$/, '$1'));
const pm = dateString.indexOf('pm') >= 0;

if (pm) hours += 12;
hours = (hours + offset) % 24;

console.log(`${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`);
```